# Using a Global RewriteRule After Redirect 301 Rules Have Not Been Matched

Tags: .htaccess

Last year we changed a large site from oldsite.com to newsite.com. During that process we placed a global RewriteRule that worked like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And it worked well for the better part of a year. But Google held onto a few old records at oldsite.com while the paths changed at newsite.com. So now when the original URL is found on a Google search, they hit oldsite.com/example and it's redirected to newsite.com/example, but the real URL is now newsite.com/not-example.

We placed some 301 redirects at oldsite.com that looked like this:

```
redirect 301 /something/ https://newsite.com/new-thing/
```

I confirmed that if we remove the RewriteRule, those will work. But since we have 3000+ URLs on the old site we can't really just kill that global rule. Writing/generating 3000+ URLs that might change also didn't feel like a sane route either.

I had read that the Redirect rule and RewriteRule are in two conflicting modules, and that they won't work together. So I started to test the new rules as RewriteRules. That looked like this:

```
RewriteRule ^/something/ https://newsite.com/new-thing/ [R=301,L]
```

I tried things like using ^(.*)something/, ^(.*)/something/, and ^/something$ to see if I could make the match. Once in awhile it would redirect me to things like https://newsite.com/newsite.com/new-thing/. But usually it just followed that global rule.

**So the first question is**, what is the correct way to write a single-URL RedirectRule, and is that even advisable? (I was under the impression they should be used for pattern matching, not individual URLs).

**The second question is,** how do you keep other patterns like ^(.*)$ from overriding them? I had also read that the "L" flag has something to do with this, but it didn't seem to make a difference either way.

I sincerely appreciate the help on this, it has been taunting me all day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have all rules using same directive i.e. `RewriteRule`.
2. Keep specific rules before generic rule.

So have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# known URI 1
RewriteRule ^/?something(/.*)?$ https://newsite.com/new-thing/ [R=301,L,NC]

# known URI 2
RewriteRule ^/?something-else(/.*)?$ https://newsite.com/new-thing2/ [R=301,L,NC]

# generic rule
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```